# Responsive Web Design not working where only one div should be displayed depending on the page width

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, responsiveness

I'm trying to build a page where 1 div will be chosen according to the page width. I've checked and rechecked my whole code from upside down and can't seen to figure out what's wrong.

For example, we have:
1
2
3
4
5

If the page is over 800 pixels width, then it will only display the div 5.
If the page is 320 pixels width, it will display the div 1, if 480 pixels width, then div 2, and so on...

Here:

```
<style> body { margin:0; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:large; } 


/*  */
@media screen and (max-width: 324px) {
#graficorelatorio1 {
         overflow: hidden;
         width: 254px;
         height: 153px;
         clear:both;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
         margin-bottom:1rem;
         margin-top:1rem;
    }
#graficorelatorio2, #graficorelatorio3, #graficorelatorio4, #graficorelatorio5 { display:none;
    }   
}
/*  */
@media screen and (max-width: 490px) and (min-width: 325px){    

#graficorelatorio2 {
         overflow: hidden;
         width: 324px;
         height: 194px;
         clear:both;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
         margin-bottom:1rem;
         margin-top:1rem;
    }
#graficorelatorio1, #graficorelatorio3, #graficorelatorio4, #graficorelatorio5 { display:none;
    }   

}   
/*  */
@media screen and (max-width: 624px) and (min-width: 491px) {   
#graficorelatorio3 {
         overflow: hidden;
         width: 483px;
         height: 228px;
         clear:both;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
         margin-bottom:1rem;
         margin-top:1rem;
}
#graficorelatorio1, #graficorelatorio2, #graficorelatorio4, #graficorelatorio5 { display:none;
    }   

}   
/* */@media screen and (max-width:839px) and (min-width: 625px) {
#graficorelatorio4 {
         overflow: hidden;
         width: 624px;
         height: 289px;
         clear:both;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
         margin-bottom:1rem;
         margin-top:1rem;
}
#graficorelatorio1, #graficorelatorio2, #graficorelatorio3, #graficorelatorio5 { display:none;
    }   

}   

/**/
@media screen and and (min-width: 840px) {  
 #graficorelatorio5 {
         overflow: hidden;
         width: 841px;
         height: 321px;
         clear:both;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
         margin-bottom:1rem;
         margin-top:1rem;
}
#graficorelatorio1, #graficorelatorio2, #graficorelatorio3, #graficorelatorio4 { display:none;
    }   
}       


 #mainrelatorio {
         background-color: #134F5C;
         overflow:hidden;
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
         display:block;
    }




</style>


<div id="mainrelatorio">


<!-- width="254" height="152.3110834864699" -->
<div id="graficorelatorio1">
1
</div>

<!-- width="323.0698621553885" height="193.6110834864699" -->
<div id="graficorelatorio2">
2
</div>

<!--  width="483" height="227.67577137343096"-->
<div id="graficorelatorio3">
 3
</div>

<!-- width="623.5" height="288.84898929845417"-->
<div id="graficorelatorio4">
  4
</div>

<!-- 841" height="321" -->
<div id="graficorelatorio5">
   5
</div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one**

```css
.show-box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: crimson;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 275px;
    margin: 75px auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    .four, .three, .two, .one {
      display: none; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 621px) {
    .five, .three, .two, .one {
      display: none; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) and (min-width: 421px) {
    .five, .four, .two, .one {
      display: none; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) and (min-width: 321px) {
    .five, .four, .three, .one {
      display: none; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .five, .four, .three, .two {
      display: none; 
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="show-box five">5</div>
<div class="show-box four">4</div>
<div class="show-box three">3</div>
<div class="show-box two">2</div>
<div class="show-box one">1</div>
```

Comment: This was my first approach before I come here. Sucks it was my browser the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is working but you don't see it because the numbers are white with a white background.

Here is your code working with a black background color:
https://jsfiddle.net/2h41ny05/15/

```
#graficorelatorio1 {
         overflow: hidden;
         width: 254px;
         height: 153px;
         clear:both;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
         margin-bottom:1rem;
         margin-top:1rem;
         background-color: black;
    }
```

Comment: oh sorry, I actually see it, but I forgot to paste the part of the code responsible for the background. I'll update the question.

Comment: Dude, you said that the only thing wrong was the background. Well, I place the part responsible for the background in the question. Then I tested both old (Mine) and new (Yours) codes, my code isn't working.
Didn't you change anything beside the background color?

Comment: And that extra "and", I removed it. Still the same thing.

Comment: I've added the "mainrelatorio" div and is still working. Check the fiddle again. What's not working for you? The numbers are inside the "graficorelatorio" divs.

Comment: Found out. It's a browser problem. Using Chrome. I tested with Firefox and it worked. It's funny because when I test your fiddle, it works. Already cleared the cache.

Comment: I've checked with Safari and Chrome, both are working.

Comment: Yes, it's from my side. I don't know what it is and personally I don't care. As far as it's working.. Well, thanks.

Comment: I had marked your answer as the best one, but then I saw the other dude's answer. You've been of a great help, but I'll mark his answer as the best one because he put a lot of effort into it and because it's a simpler approach. Thank you anyway.